# RegEx to match stuff between parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, url, url-routing

I'm having a tough time getting this to work. I have a string like:

```
something/([0-9])/([a-z])
```

And I need regex or a method of getting each match between the parentheses and return an array of matches like:

```
[
  [0-9],
  [a-z]
]
```

The regex I'm using is `/\((.+)\)/` which does seem to match the right thing **if** there is only **one** set of parenthesis.

How can I get an array like above using any RegExp method in JavaScript? I need to return just that array because the *returned* items in the array will be looped through to create a URL routing scheme.

Comment: When you say "one set of parentheses", are you referring to *nested* parentheses?  It's basically beyond the power of regular expressions to understand the whole "balanced parentheses" thing.

Comment: _Anything_ inside of the `()`. So if the string was `something/([0-9])/((a)(b))` it'd return `[ [0-9], (a)(b) ]`. Im not going to validate these, just throwing em inside a `new RegExp()`

Answer (score 157, accepted):

You need to make your regex pattern 'non-greedy' by adding a `?` after the `.+`

By default, `*` and `+` are greedy in that they will match as long a string of chars as possible, ignoring any matches that might occur within the string.

Non-greedy makes the pattern only match the shortest possible match.

See [Watch Out for The Greediness!](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for a better explanation.

Or alternately, change your regex to

```
\(([^\)]+)\)
```

which will match any grouping of parentheses that do not, themselves, contain parentheses.

Comment: Perfect, that matches it! but im stuck at how to get make an array from that? I just get `["([0-9])"]` with `str.match(/\([^\)]+\)/g)` :(

Comment: You're missing the internal start and end capture parens. Try /\\(([^)]+)\\)/g which will capture all possible parenthesized values. Note the *second* pair of parens after \\( and before \\).

Comment: Thanks for the "greedy" part. Helped a lot.

Comment: In my case to include parens that do not contain any other parens, I had to add open parens to the regex:

      `\(([^\)(]+)\)`

Comment: This is great, but is there a way to not match the actual parens themselves? I can always remove the first and last character of every match, but it would be nice if it could all be done in one line.

Comment: The simplest way would be to do a replace and take the result, as in: `result=str.replace(/^.+?\(([^\)]+)\).+$/,'$1')` which will replace a string that contains a parenthesized span of text with the text itself. See https://jsfiddle.net/b3rs34d4/

Comment: And here's a one-liner that extracts all parenthesized values from a multi-lined string... https://jsfiddle.net/pv8pzL6j/

Comment: And just for the record, for complex extractions I've found regexen to be of limited value due to their complexity and lack of easy readability. Adding multi-line, free-whitespaced and commented sugar like [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) helps a lot, but I've found writing a job-specific parser using [PegJS](https://pegjs.org/) to be invaluable. I'm happy to explain more if anyone's interested.

Answer (score 17):

Use this expression:

```
/\(([^()]+)\)/g
```

e.g:

```
function()
{
    var mts = "something/([0-9])/([a-z])".match(/\(([^()]+)\)/g );
    alert(mts[0]);
    alert(mts[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If s is your string:

```
s.replace(/^[^(]*\(/, "") // trim everything before first parenthesis
 .replace(/\)[^(]*$/, "") // trim everything after last parenthesis
 .split(/\)[^(]*\(/);      // split between parenthesis
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var getMatchingGroups = function(s) {
  var r=/\((.*?)\)/g, a=[], m;
  while (m = r.exec(s)) {
    a.push(m[1]);
  }
  return a;
};

getMatchingGroups("something/([0-9])/([a-z])"); // => ["[0-9]", "[a-z]"]
```