# How to parse in javascript all regex between one or more parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse all of the text between one or more parentheses and return an array.

For example:

```
var string = "((CID:34746) OR (CID:8097)) ((CID:34277 OR CID:67300))";
var regex = /\(([^()]+)\)/g;
var results = string.match(regex);
// should result in ["CID:34746","CID:8097","CID:34277 OR CID:67300"]
// but instead is ["(CID:34746)", "(CID:8097)", "(CID:34277 OR CID:67300)"]
```

I've had 3 people on my team try to find a solution and nobody has.  I've looked at all the ones I can find on SO and otherwise.  ([This one is where I posted the above regex from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208367/regex-to-match-stuff-between-parentheses)...)

The closest I've gotten is: /([^()]+)/g.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.match()` will return an array of whole matches only, if you use the `g`lobal modifier. Use [`.exec()` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) instead:

```
var match,
    results = [];

while(match = regex.exec(string)) {
    results.push(match[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is correct you're just not using it right:

```
var string = "((CID:34746) OR (CID:8097)) ((CID:34277 OR CID:67300))";
var regex = /\(([^()]+)\)/g;
var desiredResults = [];
var results;
while( results = regex.exec(string) ) {
    desiredResults.push( results[1] );
}
// now desiredResults is ["CID:34746","CID:8097","CID:34277 OR CID:67300"]
```