# Putting quotes around text: find and replace with regex

Tags: regex, atom-editor

In Atom, I'm working with a huge text file and I have to replace any occurrences of

```
.env(bar)
```

with

```
.env('bar')
```

where `bar` can have several values, with the standard Find-Replace tool.

I successfully managed to select (Find field) the patterns I want to change thanks to

```
.env(\(([^\)]+)\))
```

as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208367/regex-to-match-stuff-between-parentheses).

However I cannot find any proper regex to fill into the Replace field in order to wrap between quotes, e.g. none of these work:

```
.env(\'\(([^\)]+)\)\')
.env('\(([^\)]+)\)')
```

Moreover, how can I revert the whole process (also using Find-Replace regex)?

Thanks!

Comment: In replace field you can't use regular expressions but replacement strings such as referencing to captured groups. Find `\.env\(([^)]+)\)`, Replace with `.env('$1')`

Comment: You try get the `.env(bar)` and replace for `.env('bar')`, rigth ? In this moment you can find the `.env(bar)` ? but cant replace with quotes  the value of `bar`? Is this correct ?

Comment: You cant get the capture group with $1, check the @revo comment..

Comment: @revo bullseye. Also finding `\.env\(\'([^)]+)\'\)` and replacing `.env($1)` reverts the whole thing. If you're willing to properly answer the question, I'll be very happy to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While a pattern matches you can't fill replacement field with Regular Expressions because simply it doesn't work that way. You can't use Regular Expressions, but instead, replacement strings such as referencing to recent captured groups are available.

1. Find: `\.env\(([^)]+)\)`
2. Replace with: `.env('$1')`

*`$1` means capturing group #1*