# Get array of matching strings

Tags: ruby, regex

From a given string I want an array of all the substrings within the parenthesis of given string for example I have a string

```
COUNTER_SUM(lehr_in) / COUNTER_SUM(feeder) * 100
```

Here I have two substrings within the parenthises "lehr_in" and "feeder" so my result should be

```
["lehr_in", "feeder"]
```

Comment: What are `COUNTER_SUM`, `lehr_in`, `feeder`?

Comment: Where is the regular expression?

Comment: Did you mean COUNTER_SUM(lehr_in) / COUNTER_SUM(feeder) * 100 is string? Like so: `"COUNTER_SUM(lehr_in) / COUNTER_SUM(feeder) * 100"` ? And you'd want to catch string between paranthesis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx to match stuff between parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208367/regex-to-match-stuff-between-parentheses)

Comment: yes @Surya "COUNTER_SUM(lehr_in) / COUNTER_SUM(feeder) * 100" is a string and I want you guys to help me to write out the regular expression in ruby so that I can get array of substrings from expression with in the parenthesis. Example is given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better way to do this using regexes, but here's what I came up with:

```
a.split(/[^(]*\(([^)]+)\)[^(]*/).reject(&:empty?)
```