# Extracting words in parentheses and store the extracted words into a set

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my current code:

```
folder_path1 = os.chdir("C:/Users/xx/Documents/xxx/Test python dict")

words= set()
extracted = set()
for file in os.listdir(folder_path1):
   if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
      wb = load_workbook(file, data_only=True)
      ws = wb.active
      words.add(str(ws['A1'].value))

      wordsextract = re.match(r"(.*)\((.*)\)", str(words))

      extracted.add(str(wordsextract))
      print(extracted)
```

I'm not sure how to extract only the words inside the parentheses. Hence, I thought it was possible to do a re.match parentheses to extract the words within the parentheses. But it's not working. Does anyone here have knowledge on this? Thanks a bunch in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx to match stuff between parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208367/regex-to-match-stuff-between-parentheses)

Comment: else you would need lazy evaluation: `r'\((.+?)\)'` to get the shortest possible word between parentheses and probably findall with it...

Comment: hey @PatrickArtner thank you for your response!! :) I tried your code: `cellvalue.split("(")[-1].split(")")[0]` but there seems to be a syntax error..

Comment: `set(re.findall("\((.+?)\)", words)` doesn't work?

Comment: @PatrickArtner thank you so much, your first answer worked and I have incorporated it as such:
wordsextract = re.findall(r"\((.+?)\)", str(cellvalues))

Comment: @palvarez thank you so much, yes it worked after i cleaned up my codes as well! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the whole column into a set, extract words from each cell value:

Excel-Source:

[image: excel file content image]

Program:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import re
import os

folder_path1 = os.chdir("C:/temp/")

words= set()
extracted = set()
for file in os.listdir(folder_path1):
    if file.endswith("m1.xlsx"):
        wb = load_workbook(file, data_only=True)
        ws = wb.active
        # this is A1 though to A5 - yours is only one cell though, you can change the 
        # min/max to include more columns or rows

        # a set makes no sense here - you read only one cell anyhow, so anything in
        # it is your single possible value string
        # wb.iter_cols(min_col, max_col, min_row, max_row, values_only)
        content = set( *ws.iter_cols(1,1,1,5,True)) - {None} # remove empty cells

        # non-greedy capturing of things in parenthesis
        words = re.findall(r"\((.+?)\)", ' '.join(content), re.DOTALL)
        print(words)
```

Output:

```
['problem', 'span \nlines', 'some'] # out of order due to set usage
```

To do the same with splitting:

```
# same content as above
for cellvalue in content:
    if set("()").intersection(cellvalue) == {"(",")"}:
        print(cellvalue.split("(")[-1].split(")")[0])
```

HTH

Documentation:

- [worksheet.iter_cols](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=iter_cols#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_cols)
- [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)