# Remove text between two square brackets in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I change this:

```
This is a string [[remove]] this
```

To:

```
This is a string this
```

I managed to figure out how to remove a string between one set of brackets but I couldn't get it right with two:

```
var myString = "This is my string [remove] this"
myString.replace(/ *\[[^\]]*]/, '');
```

Comment: Just double the literal brackets in your regex. Although you only have one opening literal bracket.

Comment: You didn't do anything in that regex to make it work with two!? Did you try to put two of `\[` and `]` in it  instead of one??

Comment: Add another set of escaped brackets: `\[\[.*\]\]`

Comment: yes I tried and removes the string but removes everything after also

Comment: @Wiktor  I think OP has trouble with replacing two brackets `[[` and `]]` instead of replacing multiple sets of matches. Although the dupe is still relevant for the latter case.

Comment: Yeah, I am looking for a better dupe. It sounded as if OP could not remove more than 1 occurrence

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I absolutely see where you're coming from with the mention of "couldn't get it right with two". But unfortunately, I'm not sure there is a really good dupe that covers this. It's "how do I match stuff between <symbols>" (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208367/regex-to-match-stuff-between-parentheses)?) about the pattern and [What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) about how to match brackets.

Comment: @VLAZ  Well, this seems to be a pure regex issue, so I added some JS and non-JS related dupe links that dwell on matching double `[[` and `]]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew also found [this question about square brackets specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets) it's almost a complete dupe. EDIT: actually, you've found questions about double square brackets...

Comment: I can remove single [] but the problem appears with two [[]]. I tried all the duplicate posts without any good results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is expression without regarding nested `[[]]` `myString.replace(/\[\[[^\]]*\]\]/g,'');` It is tricky thing to track  nested including of pair of symbols

Comment: nothing match but it does not work with `[[ 22 ]]]]` for example it is replaced only this part `[[ 22 ]]`