# Problem matching parenthesis in awk regex

Tags: regex, awk

I have this expression

```
if lbVar and ldcVar < 0.00
```

And i need to match the right part of "and" that may contain parenthesis.

The expression to match without the parenthesis is already done:

```
 if(match(linha, /(\t| )*(and)(\t| )+(\<ldc\w*)[ \t]*(<)[ \t]*(ldc\w*|[0-9]|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*))/) > 0){ 
        print "match: "substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH);
    }
```

The problem is the expression may appear as:

```
if lbVar and ( ldcVar < 0.00 )
```

How can i correct my regex so that match both situation, that is, with or without parenthesis?

Thanks

Comment: Please do mention sample of input and expected output in your post and let us know then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx to match stuff between parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208367/regex-to-match-stuff-between-parentheses)

Comment: You have asked a few questions about regex matching. Perhaps you want to build a parser for this language instead.

Comment: We are using awk to convert powerbuilder code into java.

Answer (score 0):

There are few typos in the sequence. Trying using the modified RE below

```
if(match(line, /(\t| )*(and)(\t| )(\(+)(\t| )*(\<ldc\w*)[ \t]*(<)[ \t]*(ldc\w*|[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*))[ \t]*(\))/) ) {
    print "SUB: ="substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) "=" 
}
```

Also, consider changing the (\t| )* to [\t ]* (for efficiency/simplification).

Comment: I made the test but unfortunately didn´t match

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for `\<`.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for highlighting this. Side note: I believe that the `\<` is not needed at all in the pattern, as the pattern require tab/space/'<' before the 'ldc' token.

Comment: Could be. Right now in a non-gawk that `\<` means your regexp requires a literal `<` before the `ldc`.

Comment: I just noticed you have `\w` in the regexp - that's non-POSIX (gawk-only?) too.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't all you need:

```
awk 'match($0,/.*[[:space:]]+and[[:space:]]+/){print substr($0,RLENGTH+1)}' file
( ldcVar < 0.00 )
```

then update your question to clarify your requirements and provide a more representative sample input/output that we can test a potential solution against for a simple pass/fail result.

Comment: This isn't what i need. The regex must match the right part of the and , and match if the right part is between parenthesis, like the example: if lbVar and ( ldcVar < 0.00 )

Comment: then update your question to better describe your requirements and provide a better example

Comment: OK, there still isn't a good enough description or enough matching and non-matching in-context use cases present in your question for me personally to be able to help you more (1 sunny-day input example doesn't tell us much and I still don't know if the parentheses are required or not) but hopefully someone else will be able to. Good luck!